# delete checked radio button on option change

Tags: jquery, uikit

I have a form that does not allow "conditions" to be created. The first radio input selects "yes" or "no," then it can choose "other" and a free text field appears. The problem is that if I fill in the first radio button and then choose the second one it resets everything. I would like it to reset only the fields inherent to si or no and other.

```js
const $rads = $("input[type='radio']").on("change", function() {
  let siClicked = this.id === 'documentazione_Sì';
  let noClicked = this.id === 'documentazione_No';
  const showAltro = this.id === 'documentazione_nono_altro' || this.id === 'documentazione_ok_altro';
  if (siClicked || noClicked) {
    $rads.each(function() { // uncheck all rads
      this.checked = false;
    });
    this.checked = true; // check the clicked rad
  }
  let si = $('#documentazione_Sì').is(":checked");
  let no = $('#documentazione_No').is(":checked");
  $("#documentazione_ok")
    .toggle(si)
    .prop('required', si);
  $('#documentazione_nono')
    .toggle(no)
    .prop('required', no);
  // showAltro could also be set using the altro checked prop
  $("#altro-manuali").toggle(showAltro);
  $("#altro-manuali").prop('required', showAltro);
});
```

```css
#documentazione_ok {
  display:none;
}

#documentazione_nono {
  display:none;
}

#altro-manuali {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.19.1/css/uikit-core.min.css" integrity="sha512-61ZZY3YIjr821vHbtfOTRIGYiRSPE6nA5IVt8ndGZcXa2iRfAcuWPAdt7HyQC23AGo1+dwAd+DOPUzz64K6GsA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<h1 class="uk-h3 uk-margin-remove-top uk-margin-remove-bottom" data-id="page#1-0-1-7" data-element="">        Title    
</h1>
<div data-id="page#1-0-1-2" data-element="" class="rate2 uk-margin">
    <fieldset data-yooessentials-form-field="tempi" style="border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><div class="uk-form-controls">
        <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid" uk-grid="">
    
    
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right uk-first-column">            <div><input id="star1" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="1" data-id="page#1-0-1-2-0"></div>
            <div class="uk-margin-small-left">1</div>
        </label>
    
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">            <div><input id="star2" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="2" data-id="page#1-0-1-2-1"></div>
            <div class="uk-margin-small-left">2</div>
        </label>
    
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">            <div><input id="star3" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="3" data-id="page#1-0-1-2-2"></div>
            <div class="uk-margin-small-left">3</div>
        </label>
    
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">            <div><input id="star4" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="4" data-id="page#1-0-1-2-3"></div>
            <div class="uk-margin-small-left">4</div>
        </label>
    
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">            <div><input id="star5" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="5" data-id="page#1-0-1-2-4"></div>
            <div class="uk-margin-small-left">5</div>
        </label>
    
        </div>
    
    </div><div class="uk-text-danger uk-text-small" data-yooessentials-form-field-errors=""></div></fieldset>
</div>
<div data-id="page#1-0-1-8" data-element="" class="uk-margin" id="sino">
    <fieldset data-yooessentials-form-field="documentazione" style="border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid" uk-grid="">
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right uk-first-column">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_Sì" type="radio" name="documentazionetest" class="uk-radio domanda" value="Sì" data-id="page#1-0-1-8-0"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">Sì            </div>
                </label>
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_No" type="radio" name="documentazionetest" class="uk-radio domanda" value="No" data-id="page#1-0-1-8-1"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">No    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-text-danger uk-text-small" data-yooessentials-form-field-errors=""></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div data-id="page#1-0-1-9" data-element="" id="documentazione_ok" class="uk-margin" style="display: none;">
    <fieldset data-yooessentials-form-field="documentazione_ok" style="border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid uk-grid-stack" uk-grid="">
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right uk-first-column">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_ok_Il manuale non trattava il caso specifico" type="radio" name="documentazione_ok" class="uk-radio" value="Il manuale non trattava il caso specifico" data-id="page#1-0-1-9-0"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">1</div>
                </label>
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_ok_Il manuale non era chiaro" type="radio" name="documentazione_ok" class="uk-radio" value="Il manuale non era chiaro" data-id="page#1-0-1-9-1"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">2</div>
                </label>
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_ok_altro" type="radio" name="documentazione_ok" class="uk-radio" value="altro" data-id="page#1-0-1-9-2"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">Altro</div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-text-danger uk-text-small" data-yooessentials-form-field-errors=""></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div data-id="page#1-0-1-10" data-element="" id="documentazione_nono" class="uk-margin">
    <fieldset data-yooessentials-form-field="documentazione_nono" style="border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid" uk-grid="">
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right uk-first-column">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_nono_Il manuale cartaceo non era presente" type="radio" name="documentazione_nono" class="uk-radio" value="Il manuale cartaceo non era presente" data-id="page#1-0-1-10-0"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">3</div>
                </label>
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_nono_Non ho accesso all’area riservata del sito" type="radio" name="documentazione_nono" class="uk-radio" value="Non ho accesso all’area riservata del sito" data-id="page#1-0-1-10-1"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">4</div>
                </label>
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_nono_Non sapevo dove reperirli" type="radio" name="documentazione_nono" class="uk-radio" value="Non sapevo dove reperirli" data-id="page#1-0-1-10-2"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">5</div>
                </label>
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_nono_altro" type="radio" name="documentazione_nono" class="uk-radio" value="altro" data-id="page#1-0-1-10-3"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">Altro</div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-text-danger uk-text-small" data-yooessentials-form-field-errors=""></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div data-id="page#1-0-1-11" data-element="" id="altro-manuali" class="uk-margin" style="display: none;">
    <div data-yooessentials-form-field="altromanuali">
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <textarea class="uk-textarea" id="altromanuali" name="altromanuali"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-text-danger uk-text-small" data-yooessentials-form-field-errors=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the script.

Clear all rads EXCEPT if their ID starts with `star` when clicking Sí or No, and then toggle relevant divs

```js
const $rads = $("input[type='radio']").not("[id^=star]").on("change", function() {
  let siClicked = this.id === 'documentazione_Sì';
  let noClicked = this.id === 'documentazione_No';
  const showAltro = this.id === 'documentazione_nono_altro' || this.id === 'documentazione_ok_altro';
  if (siClicked || noClicked) {
    $rads.each(function() { // uncheck all rads
      this.checked = false;
    });
    this.checked = true; // check the clicked rad
  }
  let si = $('#documentazione_Sì').is(":checked");
  let no = $('#documentazione_No').is(":checked");
  $("#documentazione_ok")
    .toggle(si)
    .prop('required', si);
  $('#documentazione_nono')
    .toggle(no)
    .prop('required', no);
  // showAltro could also be set using the altro checked prop
  $("#altro-manuali").toggle(showAltro);
  $("#altro-manuali").prop('required', showAltro);
});
```

```css
#documentazione_ok {
  display: none;
}

#documentazione_nono {
  display: none;
}

#altro-manuali {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.19.1/css/uikit-core.min.css" integrity="sha512-61ZZY3YIjr821vHbtfOTRIGYiRSPE6nA5IVt8ndGZcXa2iRfAcuWPAdt7HyQC23AGo1+dwAd+DOPUzz64K6GsA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<h1 class="uk-h3 uk-margin-remove-top uk-margin-remove-bottom" data-id="page#1-0-1-7" data-element="">        Title    
</h1>
<div data-id="page#1-0-1-2" data-element="" class="rate2 uk-margin">
    <fieldset data-yooessentials-form-field="tempi" style="border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;"><div class="uk-form-controls">
        <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid" uk-grid="">
    
    
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right uk-first-column">            <div><input id="star1" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="1" data-id="page#1-0-1-2-0"></div>
            <div class="uk-margin-small-left">1</div>
        </label>
    
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">            <div><input id="star2" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="2" data-id="page#1-0-1-2-1"></div>
            <div class="uk-margin-small-left">2</div>
        </label>
    
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">            <div><input id="star3" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="3" data-id="page#1-0-1-2-2"></div>
            <div class="uk-margin-small-left">3</div>
        </label>
    
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">            <div><input id="star4" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="4" data-id="page#1-0-1-2-3"></div>
            <div class="uk-margin-small-left">4</div>
        </label>
    
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">            <div><input id="star5" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="5" data-id="page#1-0-1-2-4"></div>
            <div class="uk-margin-small-left">5</div>
        </label>
    
        </div>
    
    </div><div class="uk-text-danger uk-text-small" data-yooessentials-form-field-errors=""></div></fieldset>
</div>
<div data-id="page#1-0-1-8" data-element="" class="uk-margin" id="sino">
    <fieldset data-yooessentials-form-field="documentazione" style="border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid" uk-grid="">
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right uk-first-column">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_Sì" type="radio" name="documentazionetest" class="uk-radio domanda" value="Sì" data-id="page#1-0-1-8-0"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">Sì            </div>
                </label>
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_No" type="radio" name="documentazionetest" class="uk-radio domanda" value="No" data-id="page#1-0-1-8-1"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">No    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-text-danger uk-text-small" data-yooessentials-form-field-errors=""></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div data-id="page#1-0-1-9" data-element="" id="documentazione_ok" class="uk-margin" style="display: none;">
    <fieldset data-yooessentials-form-field="documentazione_ok" style="border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid uk-grid-stack" uk-grid="">
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right uk-first-column">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_ok_Il manuale non trattava il caso specifico" type="radio" name="documentazione_ok" class="uk-radio" value="Il manuale non trattava il caso specifico" data-id="page#1-0-1-9-0"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">1</div>
                </label>
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_ok_Il manuale non era chiaro" type="radio" name="documentazione_ok" class="uk-radio" value="Il manuale non era chiaro" data-id="page#1-0-1-9-1"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">2</div>
                </label>
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_ok_altro" type="radio" name="documentazione_ok" class="uk-radio" value="altro" data-id="page#1-0-1-9-2"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">Altro</div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-text-danger uk-text-small" data-yooessentials-form-field-errors=""></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div data-id="page#1-0-1-10" data-element="" id="documentazione_nono" class="uk-margin">
    <fieldset data-yooessentials-form-field="documentazione_nono" style="border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid" uk-grid="">
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right uk-first-column">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_nono_Il manuale cartaceo non era presente" type="radio" name="documentazione_nono" class="uk-radio" value="Il manuale cartaceo non era presente" data-id="page#1-0-1-10-0"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">3</div>
                </label>
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_nono_Non ho accesso all’area riservata del sito" type="radio" name="documentazione_nono" class="uk-radio" value="Non ho accesso all’area riservata del sito" data-id="page#1-0-1-10-1"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">4</div>
                </label>
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_nono_Non sapevo dove reperirli" type="radio" name="documentazione_nono" class="uk-radio" value="Non sapevo dove reperirli" data-id="page#1-0-1-10-2"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">5</div>
                </label>
                <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                    <div><input id="documentazione_nono_altro" type="radio" name="documentazione_nono" class="uk-radio" value="altro" data-id="page#1-0-1-10-3"></div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-small-left">Altro</div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-text-danger uk-text-small" data-yooessentials-form-field-errors=""></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div data-id="page#1-0-1-11" data-element="" id="altro-manuali" class="uk-margin" style="display: none;">
    <div data-yooessentials-form-field="altromanuali">
        <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <textarea class="uk-textarea" id="altromanuali" name="altromanuali"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-text-danger uk-text-small" data-yooessentials-form-field-errors=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, thank you for your response... If I had multiple radios instead but would like to apply this to one radio button? Unfortunately it resets my other radio buttons as well

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean. Please update the question and be more descriptive

Comment: I redid the example in codepen, here is the link. If you try to select the first radio button and then go to the second one unfortunately the first one gets reset. codepen.io/documarketing/pen/eYXLxLd

Comment: I still do not understand. I reset all radios when you click si or no

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't make myself understood. I would like to reset only the si or no field. But if I have multiple radio buttons I would like them not to be reset by clicking si or no

Comment: But you DO have multiple radios. Please update your question and give a click by click example of what you want and what you do not have working.

Comment: I added a question at the bottom

Comment: UPDATE your question. Don't post an answer

Comment: `const $rads = $("input[type='radio']").not("[id^=star]").on("change", function() {`